# Problem with pointer to a member function

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

In code below (please see comment):

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

struct Base
{
 void fnc()
 {
  cout << "Base::fnc()";
 }

};

struct Impl
{
 void* data_;
 Impl(void (Base::*fp)())
 {
  fp();//HERE I'M INVOKING IT - I'M DOING SOMETHING WRONG!
 }
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 return 0;
}
```

**Error**
"Error 1 error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments"
Why doesn't it work and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef  int (MyClass::*memberPointer_t)(int);

...

memberPointer_t mb = &MyClass::function;
MyClass* object = getObject();

int returnValue = (object->*mb)(3);

...
```

Since it's a pointer to a member function, you must call it on an object and use the ->* or the .* operator to call it.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work because `fp` is not a function pointer but a member pointer.

How to fix it is easy, use it as it should be used: `someinstance.*fp();`

Comment: You could make the function static. Then Base::*fp();  (up vote)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are calling the function as a free function, when it isn't. It's a member function, and you need to call it in the context of an object:

```
(obj.*f)();
```

Boost.Bind offers an idiomatic way to tackle this:

```
#include<boost/bind.hpp>

// ...
Impl i(boost::bind(&Base::fnc, obj));
```

You can define the `Impl` constructor like so:

```
#include<boost/function.hpp>

// ...
Impl(boost::function<void ()> fnc)
{
    fnc();  // boost::bind translates it to obj.fnc()
}
```

If only the `Impl` object knows what object to call the function on, then you can use the placeholders of Boost.Bind:

```
Impl i(boost::bind(&Base::fnc, boost::_1));
```

And the `Impl` constructor would then be similar to

```
Impl(boost::function<void (Base)> fnc, Base& b)
{
    fnc(b);  // boost::bind translates it to b.fnc()
}
```

Sometimes it's wiser to use templates in the side that accepts the functor:

```
template<class Op>
Impl(Op fnc) { ... }
```

because then the client can pass any member function, with or without boost. But the cost is that you might have harder-to-understand compiler error messages.

Answer (score 1):

You need a Base to call the function on.

You might be looking for something more like bind() and function<> that will allow you to bind an instance and member function into a functor that can be just called like a function.

Comment: Roberts I can't see a point of using pointers to member function in that case. Why wouldn't I use the pointer to my base class and invoke any function without using this pointer to member function?

Comment: @There For the same reason, why you would use function pointer. Dynamic binding to a specific method.

Comment: @There if you know what function to call inside a class then using object (something.fnc()) is the way to go, but if you don't know the function then you need both the object and pointer to member function (something.*fp()). Those p-to-m-f's are sometimes handy, but are rarely used.

Comment: I certainly would not agree that pointer to member is a rarely used construct.  If you're adequately leveraging the STL you're probably using it a lot.

Comment: `std::for_each(shapes.begin(), shapes.end(), std::mem_fun(&Shape::draw));`

Answer (score 1):

You could benefit from reading [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html) FAQ regarding pointers to member functions.
Particularly they strongly recommend you define a macro for these calls:

`#define CALL_MEMBER_FN(object,ptrToMember)  ((object).*(ptrToMember))`